# how to print exactly matched words from string python

Tags: python, string

```
categories = [
    'java', 'java developer', 'hadoop', 'Hadoop kafka',
    'html developer', 'hibernate', 'text',
    'big data developer', 'data stage developer']

str = "looking for hadoop developer with java knowledge" 
ans = [i for i in categories 
          if all([j in str.split() for j in i.split()])]
```

output:

```
['java','java developer','hadoop']
```

'java developer' should not be printed.

I'm looking for exactly matched words and phrases.
The real categories list contains 7k elements.

Comment: Try to improve the quality of your question. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and the problems you are facing.

Comment: am facing problem with extra words.which is not present in the string is also printing and am looking for exactly matched words

Answer (score 1):

It should be no surprise that you got exactly what you asked for: phrases in which each word appears anywhere in the target string.  Since "java" and "developer" both appear in the target, you got "java developer" in your result.

If you want only exact phrase matches, then *simplify* your search to that:

```
ans = [i for i in categories if i in str]
```

I believe that solves your given problem.

Given:

```
categories = [
    'java', 'java developer', 'hadoop', 'Hadoop kafka',
    'html developer', 'hibernate', 'text',
    'big data developer', 'data stage developer']

str = "looking for hadoop developer with java knowledge"
```

Output:

```
['java', 'hadoop']
```

If we change `str`

```
str = "looking for java developer with hadoop knowledge"
```

the output changes to

```
['java', 'java developer', 'hadoop']
```

In other words, my original posting solves both your original problem and your extended problem.

Comment: See the update to my answer, which solved this problem as well.  If you have further requirements that conflict with these, please post a new question with the new (larger) problem.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.